# GWT RequestFactory ошибка компиляции в NetBeans

Tags: maven, gwt, java, netbeans

Есть проблем а с запуском простейшего GWT-приложения, использующего RequestFactory. GWT-RPC отрабатывает на ура. RequestFactory всегда валится на этапе компиляции.
Использую NetBeans, Maven, GWT 2.4.0

Несколько шагов компиляции с ошибкой в конце:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: C:\Programs\NetBeans 7.1.1\java\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.6.0_26, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Programs (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

......................................................

[gwt:compile]
org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:2.2.0:
   com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0:runtime
      javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:runtime
      javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:runtime
   com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.4.0:runtime
   com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.4.0:runtime
   com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-server:jar:2.4.0:runtime
      org.json:json:jar:20090211:runtime
   com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-apt:jar:2.4.0:runtime
   org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:runtime
      org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
   org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9:compile
         org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9:compile
      org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
   org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile
   org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1:compile
      org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
         commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
            commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
      commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
         commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
         commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
         oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
   org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0:compile
   org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.1.4:compile
      org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.4:compile
      org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.4:compile
      org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.4:compile
      org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.4:compile
      org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile
      org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile
      org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
      commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
   org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
      org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
      commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
   com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12:compile
   freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.6:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
      org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0-alpha-1:compile
   org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.1:compile
      org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13:compile
   junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:compile
   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3:compile
   org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3:compile
   commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
   org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
   jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
      dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
      jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
      xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
      xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
         xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
         xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
         com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
   org.apache.bcel:bcel:jar:5.2:compile
      jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile
   xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
   classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.5.3:compile
   org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:1.5.3:compile
Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0
Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0
  Imported:  < maven.api
Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0
  Included: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:jar:2.2.0
  Included: com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0
  Included: javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA
  Included: javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA
  Included: com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.4.0
  Included: com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.4.0
  Included: com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-server:jar:2.4.0
  Included: org.json:json:jar:20090211
  Included: com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-apt:jar:2.4.0
  Included: org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final
  Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6
  Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0
  Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.2
  Included: commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1
  Included: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2
  Included: commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0
  Included: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0
  Included: commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6
  Included: oro:oro:jar:2.0.8
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.1.4
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.4
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.4
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.4
  Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.4
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7
  Included: org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5
  Included: commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2
  Included: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE
  Included: org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE
  Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
  Included: com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12
  Included: freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.6
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.0-alpha-9
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0-alpha-1
  Included: org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.1
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13
  Included: junit:junit:jar:4.8.1
  Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3
  Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3
  Included: commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5
  Included: org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1
  Included: jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1
  Included: dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1
  Included: jdom:jdom:jar:1.0
  Included: xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02
  Included: xom:xom:jar:1.0
  Included: xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2
  Included: xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0
  Included: com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1
  Included: org.apache.bcel:bcel:jar:5.2
  Included: jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4
  Included: xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.5.3
  Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:1.5.3
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9
  Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
  Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2
Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@d9f9c3]
Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0:compile' with basic configurator -->
  (f) compileReport = true
  (f) disableCastChecking = false
  (f) disableClassMetadata = false
  (f) draftCompile = false
  (f) enableAssertions = false
  (f) extra = D:\proj\Java\GWT\gwtapp\target\extra
  (f) extraJvmArgs = -Xmx512m
  (f) extraParam = false
  (f) force = false
  (f) gen = D:\proj\Java\GWT\gwtapp\target\.generated
  (f) generateDirectory = D:\proj\Java\GWT\gwtapp\target\generated-sources\gwt
  (f) gwtSdkFirstInClasspath = false
  (f) inplace = false
  (f) localRepository =        id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/casper/.m2/repository/
   layout: none

  (f) logLevel = INFO
  (f) optimizationLevel = -1
  (f) pluginArtifacts = {org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin=org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2.0:, com.google.gwt:gwt-user=com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0:runtime, javax.validation:validation-api=javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:runtime, com.google.gwt:gwt-dev=com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.4.0:runtime, com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet=com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.4.0:runtime, com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-server=com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-server:jar:2.4.0:runtime, org.json:json=org.json:json:jar:20090211:runtime, com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-apt=com.google.web.bindery:requestfactory-apt:jar:2.4.0:runtime, org.hibernate:hibernate-validator=org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:runtime, org.slf4j:slf4j-api=org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api=org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:3.0:compile, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl=org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.1.2:compile, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient=commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile, commons-codec:commons-codec=commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile, commons-validator:commons-validator=commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile, commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils=commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile, commons-digester:commons-digester=commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile, oro:oro=oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.1.4:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1.4:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.1.4:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.1.4:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml=org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.1.4:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile, org.apache.velocity:velocity=org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile, commons-collections:commons-collections=commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile, org.springframework:spring-core=org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-asm=org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging=commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox=com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.12:compile, freemarker:freemarker=freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.6:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0-alpha-1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-archiver=org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13:compile, junit:junit=junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:compile, org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter=org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.4.3:compile, org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api=org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.4.3:compile, commons-lang:commons-lang=commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile, org.jdom:jdom=org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile, jaxen:jaxen=jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile, dom4j:dom4j=dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile, jdom:jdom=jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile, xml-apis:xml-apis=xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile, xom:xom=xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile, xerces:xmlParserAPIs=xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile, xalan:xalan=xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile, com.ibm.icu:icu4j=com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.bcel:bcel=org.apache.bcel:bcel:jar:5.2:compile, jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp=jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile, xerces:xercesImpl=xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:1.5.3:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac=org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:1.5.3:compile}
  (f) project = MavenProject: ru.itskills.gwtapp:App:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\proj\Java\GWT\gwtapp\pom.xml
  (f) remoteRepositories = [       id: central
      url: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
  (f) skip = false
  (f) soyc = false
  (f) soycDetailed = false
  (f) strict = false
  (f) style = OBF
  (f) treeLogger = false
  (f) validateOnly = false
  (f) version = 2.2.0
  (f) warSourceDirectory = D:\proj\Java\GWT\gwtapp\src\main\webapp
  (f) webappDirectory = D:\proj\Java\GWT\gwtapp\target\App-1.0-SNAPSHOT
-- end configuration --

......................................................

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0:compile (default) on project App: GWT Module com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.2.0:compile (default) on project App: GWT Module com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory not found in project sources or resources.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GWT Module com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory not found in project sources or resources.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.utils.GwtModuleReaderException: GWT Module com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory not found in project sources or resources.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java:205)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getLocalInherits(GwtModule.java:186)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getInherits(GwtModule.java:146)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getEntryPoints(GwtModule.java:111)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:440)
        ... 24 more
```

А вот и pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ru.itskills.gwtapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>App</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ru.itskills.gwtapp.App</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.6 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RequestFactory -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- see sample projects for correct placement -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>target/www/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
          </dependency>

            <!-- RequestFactory -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- see sample projects for correct placement -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
                <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <!-- JS is only needed in the package phase, this speeds up testing -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options,
            see gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <!-- URL that should be automatically opened in the GWT shell (gwt:run). -->
          <runTarget>App.html</runTarget>
          <!-- Location of the develop-mode web application structure (gwt:run). -->
          <hostedWebapp>target/www</hostedWebapp>
          <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
          <compileReport>true</compileReport>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Add source folders to test classpath in order to run gwt-tests as normal junit-tests -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</additionalClasspathElement>
          </additionalClasspathElements>
          <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
          <forkMode>always</forkMode>

          <!-- Folder for generated testing stuff -->
          <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>gwt.args</name>
              <value>-out target/www</value>
            </property>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/www</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Delete gwt generated stuff -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset><directory>src/main/webapp/app</directory></fileset>
            <fileset><directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</directory></fileset>
            <fileset><directory>tomcat</directory></fileset>
            <fileset><directory>www-test</directory></fileset>
            <fileset><directory>.gwt-tmp</directory></fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>  <!--  Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
          <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildCommand>
              <name>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</name>
            </buildCommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Возникает ощущение, что не хватает какого-то плагина или библиотеки.
Благодарю за любую помощь!

Comment: ненавижу maven - это как раз тот случай когда на отладку сборочного скрипта тратится больше сил чем на собственно программирования. Сочувствую...

Comment: Честно говоря, у меня уже сходные чувства. Я не спонтанно вопрос задал, с этой проблемой упорно борюсь уже 5 дней. На что уже только не пенял. Пытался и без Мавена собрать, но и тут не срослось...

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найден. Помогли разобраться.

Проблема в том, что в `gwt.xml` зависимость должна прописываться так:

```
<inherits name='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.RequestFactory'>
```

не смотря на то, что в версии 2.4.0 класс находится здесь: `com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory`

Почему оно работает именно так для меня пока остаётся загадкой.